# Best way getting video url for paragraph on a node with a field video (media core)

Tags: media

When I have a **paragraph** on a node with a **field video** (media core), is there another good practice to get the URL of the video?

I have this in the twig-file **field--paragraph--field-video.html.twig**:

```
file_url(item.content['#media'].field_media_video_file.entity.uri.value)
```

Or is there a better way in a field--paragraph--* file?

Comment: What do you mean by “better”?

Comment: Under "Manage display" for the Video Media type you can set the display to "URL to file". Does that work for you? If that doesn't fit, preprocessing would probably be better. By the time you get to `.entity` in Twig you can start bypassing some key processing features in Drupal